# Initializing char array using auto keyword

Tags: c++, auto

I have been testing auto keyword and found out strange thing for me. Each letter takes 1 byte(char type), and using auto specifier size of auto variable is 4 bytes no matter what(I wasn't testing very long strings). How can it be explained?

```
char carray[] = "Some test output";
auto variable = "Some test output";

cout<<"carray: "<<sizeof(carray)<<endl;
cout<<"auto: "<<sizeof(variable);
```

Comment: `variable` is a pointer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because of array-to-pointer decay, `variable` becomes a `const char*` (with size of 4, which is somewhat surprising for me - what's your platform?).

If you want your `variable` to remain a character array, you might use `decltype(auto)`, like

```
decltype(auto) variable = "Some test output"; // sizeof(variable) is 17
```

Answer (score 1):

```
auto variable = "Some test output";
```

This declares a pointer-to-char. The size will be the same as the size of a machine word (4 bytes on a 32-bit machine, 8 bytes on a 64-bit machine typically).